# Should I avoid HTML-formatted notification e-mails?

Tags: html, email, formatting, html-email

A few years ago, it seemed to be accepted wisdom to avoid HTML formatting in favor of plain text when sending notification e-mails to users, because a) not all e-mail readers supported HTML and b) HTML-formatted e-mail was more likely to land in the user’s spam folder.

Are these arguments still valid today, or are HTML e-mails fair game now?

Any restrictions I should keep in mind?

**EDIT:**

I'm planning to use only a small subset of HTML -- bold, italic, links, lists and tables will be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe HTML is the way to go these days, all clients I have worked with use HTML to render their emails, but to keep it safe, you should send it both formats, HTML and plaintext. With .Net its simply create an AlternateView.

Here are a couple of resources that I have found very useful

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/19/design-and-build-an-email-newsletter-without-losing-your-mind/

http://www.mailchimp.com/kb/article/how-to-code-html-emails/

Comment: I would definitely agree that plain text is still a necessary part. I don't read HTML mail (as a conscious choice), and I know many coworkers and friends who have HTML disabled as well.

Answer (score 4):

Making html email work *correctly* everywhere is a very hard task (each client seems to support a different small subset of html / css etc.).

If you decide on sending `html` email, be sure to send multi-part mime messages (both html and plaintext versions in the same email) so clients which don't understand `html` can just render the text correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare your email HTML according to email templates. You can find many services for preparing and testing your html email. Just Google around.

And for sending part, prepare a plain text version of your message, and send the email as multipart. You can use an open source library like Zend Mail or an online app like MailChimp. In this way, if the client app doesn't support HTML, it's shown the plain text version instead.